# subclasses of abstract class in java

Tags: java

I am reading my former developers code.
There are several different subclasses like "numeric","Decimal" under a abstract class "element".
there is a segment of code like below.

```
for (Iterator i = children.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            Element element = (Element) i.next();
            for (int j = 0; j < element.getOccurs(); j++) {
                int end = pos + element.getLength();
                dataChildren.add(element.parse(sub(bytes, pos, end)));
                pos = end;
            }
        }
```

My question is which subclasses it will call when execute this "element.parse(sub(bytes, pos, end)"?

Comment: Whichever one happens to be stored in the `element` variable in that iteration of the loop.

Comment: It depends on the contents of `children`. It could potentially be any subclass.

Comment: Could "Element element = (Element) i.next();" decide which kind of element it is?

Comment: read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html)

Comment: I think it will exhibit normal `polymorphic` behavior.

Comment: i.Next certainly could.

Comment: Can you be more specific, it should end up adding as whatever type dataChildren contains, but what are the method signatures of sub and parse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It calls the parse method of the "right" class if this class override the method of the abstract class or the parse method in the abstract class (if implemented) otherwise.

If your children collections is {numeric, numeric, decimal, numeric}, and both numeric and decimal override the parse method in element, then the parse method will be called first in numeric instance, second in numeric, third in decimal and then in numeric.